# File program won't stop displaying garbage values

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to insert object in file and then read the object to display the student data but when It goes to display program just goes in infinite loop and starts displaying 0 which I have initialized in constructor.I am simply not getting what is happening. I am using visual studio 17 just in case anyones wondering. I even tried to create a new file named Student.txt in same directory as the program but it won't work. Can somone explain me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

//class to handle individual record
class Student 
{
public:
    char name[20];
    int year;
    char division;
    char address[50];
    int rollno;
    Student()
    {
        strcpy_s(name," ");
        strcpy_s(address, " ");
        rollno = 0;
        year = 0;
        division = 0;
    }
};
class operations
{

    public:
        void insertdata();
        void printg();
};
void operations::insertdata()
{
    int n;
    cout << "\nEnter how many student data you want to insert:";
    cin >> n;
    fstream fin;
    Student obj;
    fin.open("Student.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary| ios::trunc);
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout<<"\nFILE NOT Opened!";
    }
    for (int v = 0; v < n; v++)
    {

        cout << "\nEnter Roll no:";
        cin >> obj.rollno;
        cout << "\nEnter Name:";
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> obj.name;
        cout << "\nEnter year:";
        cin >> obj.year;
        cout << "\nEnter division:";
        cin >> obj.division;
        cout << "\nEnter Address:";
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> obj.address;
        fin.seekp(0, ios::end);
        fin.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
    }
    fin.close();
}

void operations::printg()
{
    Student obj;
    fstream fin("Student.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    fin.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "\n FIle doenst exist";
    }
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        cout << "\n" << obj.name;
        cout << "\n" << obj.year;
        cout << "\n" << obj.division;
    }
    fin.close();
}
int  main() {

    operations obj;
    obj.insertdata();
    obj.printg();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll be surprised to learn that your program completely fails to open the file, and because it doesn't bother check to check if the file open succeeds, the end result is the garbage you observed. And the reason your program completely fails to open the file is because, in `C++`, as you must know already, "\n" is the newline character, and not a string consisting of a backslash followed by the lettern "n". Now, look at the name of the file you're trying to open, and see if you can figure out your mistake all by yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Would you care to explain more , I mean does "\student" count as escape sequence "\n"?

Comment: Every backslash is an escape sequence.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, Thank you. To give path its other way around "/" ,I just copied path from windows explorer without even thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few wrong things:

- Writing objects like `fin.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));` is a bad idea. A compiler may decide to have different padding between members at any moment for your `Student` objects, so your file format is like a quantum particle: you don't really know how the file was laid out.
- `strcpy_s` takes 3 parameters, not 2. Anyway, do not use them, they are not really portable (even if they are in the C standard).
- Your paths are wrong, so the file will not open (as Sam explains in the comment).
- Even if you succeeded in opening a file, in `operations::printg()` you are not reading the file, so you will not get any data.
- Why do you have an `operations` class? I guess it is intended to be expanded in the future, but seems weird. If you do not intend to have state, use a `namespace` instead.

Comment: I changed my code , But now it prints successfully the entered data but still goes in infinite loop.Please see.

Comment: Solved it.Accepting this as a answer.